# Align images dynamically alongside bar graphs in SSRS Charts

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2008-r2, msbi

My requirement is to display images dynamically next to the bars in SSRS charts. I have been using many ways and was not able to find an apt solution to the problem.

I have used the bar graphs and a tablix to display images next to the bars. I have used an expression in order to repeat the images based on the number of the rows obtained from the dataset.

But the main problem is with the alignment of the images with the bars. Here's a pic.

[image]

And when the parameter/selection is changed the alignment of the images with the bars get scrambled.

[image]

I need to get the images adjacent to the bars just like the previous image(image1) even if the selection is changed.

Is there any way I can get through this?

Please share a solution.

Thanks.

Sai Chaitanya

Answer (score 0):

IMO your image is meaningless clutter, but anyway ...

I would insert a column into the existing Tablix (left of the current image) and move the chart inside that cell.  I would remove both axes, Titles etc so you just get a single bar in each cell.

Then I would insert another column into the existing Tablix (left of the chart) and pic the category label which you have blurred out in your image above.

Finally I would add footer rows to show an image for the X axis scale, and the X Axis title.

Comment: Hmm.. Thank you for the idea. I was able to develop using the data bars inside the tablix. But now I am not able add a legend to those data bars. Any suggestions..??

Comment: I would take the legend from your image above and insert it as an image in the tablix's header row.